# Javascript Loop Not Finished before If Statement Runs

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, sails.js

I have been stuck on this issue for some time now. I am calling an API - get the results just fine. I am saving the values to an array. The problem which I am encountering is trying to get specific values from the array. I have a for in loop running which takes time, so when the if statement is ran the loop hasn't reached that value. If I use Postman, I see that the value exists, its just the loop doesn't execute in time. Here is my code:

```
     var msg = {};
     var embed = {};
     var link = {};
     var msgIn = [];
     var rel = [];

     return SkypeService.getEvent(msg).then(function (result) {
            msg.eventsNext = result._links.next.href;           
            if (result && result.sender && result.sender.length > 0) {
                if (result.sender) {                                            
                    for (var item in result.sender) {
                        var event = result.sender[item].events;                        
                        for (var key in event) {                                
                            embed = event[key]._embedded;
                            msgIn.push(embed); 
                        }
                        for (var key in event) {
                            link = event[key].link;
                            rel.push(link);
                        }
                        // console.log(Object.entries(msgIn))                          
                        if(rel['rel'] == 'message') {
                            console.log("message is there")
                            if(msgIn.message) {
                                console.log("links exist")
                                if(msgIn.message.direction == "Incoming") {
                                    console.log("direction is there")
                                    msg.participant = msgIn.message._links.participant.href;
                                    msg.contMsg = msgIn.message._links.messaging.href;
                                    msg.msgIn = msgIn.message._links.plainMessage.href;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if(rel['rel'] == "messagingInvitation"){
                            console.log("invite there")
                            if(msgIn.messagingInvitation && msgIn.messagingInvitation.state !== "Failed") {
                                console.log("invite link") 
                                if(msgIn.messagingInvitation.direction == "incoming") {
                                    console.log("direction invite")
                                    msg.msgInviteState = msgIn.messagingInvitation._links.state;
                                    msg.acceptInvite = msgIn.messagingInvitation._links['accept'].href;
                                    msg.msgIn = msgIn.messagingInvitation._links.message.href;
                                    break;
                                }                                   
                            }
                        }
                        if(rel['rel'] == 'messaging') {
                            console.log('messaging there')
                            if(msgIn.messaging) {
                                if(msgIn.messaging.state == "Disconnected") {
                                    console.log("msgn Disconnected")
                                    msg.addMsg = msgIn.messaging._links.addMessaging.href;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }                                               
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(msg)    
        })
```

Also, I've attached a screenshot of my local host printing the msgIn which shows that the keys exists. 
[image: msgIn]

When I test the code running sails lift, I can see that msgIn prints a couple of times each one increasing in length. This is what makes me think the for loop has not completed by the time the if statement runs.

Please help - I really need for this to be resolved. I need to capture the links so that I can use those in the next step.

Thanks.

Comment: You have 3 if statements after the loops, which of them are you referring to?

Comment: You need to simplify this into a much smaller example. Just pasting some code here and asking others to debug it isn't quite right. Try to formulate a less specific example of the problem you are trying to understand how to fix.

Comment: Have you tried putting your for statements in the first .then() block, and then your if statements in the next .then block?

Comment: Confused why you're checking for result.sender in the first if and then immediately again on the very next line. I would rewrite this into something other than nested for...in loops. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Chibuzo ideally all 3. But if(rel['rel'] == 'message')  is the one of most interest. The problem is that it does catch the values at times - but not all the time even though it exists.

Comment: @RyanGibbs Yes, I have tried moving the if statements to the next .then() block which results in the same.

Comment: @mccambridge I have removed it. This API is for UCWA (quite confusing in how to handle it). But I was trying to follow similar logic I've seen on [Github](https://github.com/tomorgan/UCWASimpleWebpageChatExample/blob/master/assets/js/ucwa/helper/Events.js)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by making changes to the code. Here is the new version:

```
     return 
     SkypeService.getEvent(msg).then(function 
     (result) {
            msg.eventsNext = result._links.next.href;

            if (result.sender) {                                            
                for (var item in result.sender) {
                    var event = result.sender[item].events;                        
                    for (var key in event) {                                
                        embed = event[key]._embedded;
                        link = event[key].link;                          
                    };

                    if(link['rel'] == 'message') {
                        console.log("message is there")
                        if(embed.message) {
                            console.log("links exist")
                            if(embed.message.direction == "Incoming") {
                                console.log("direction is there")
                                msg.participant = embed.message._links.participant.href;
                                msg.contMsg = embed.message._links.messaging.href;
                                msg.msgIn = embed.message._links.plainMessage.href;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    if(link['rel'] == "messagingInvitation"){
                        console.log("invite there")
                        if(embed.messagingInvitation) {
                            console.log("invite link") 
                            if(embed.messagingInvitation.direction == "incoming") {
                                console.log("direction invite")
                                msg.msgInviteState = embed.messagingInvitation._links.state;
                                msg.acceptInvite = embed.messagingInvitation._links['accept'].href;
                                msg.msgIn = embed.messagingInvitation._links.message.href;
                                break;
                            }                                   
                        }
                    };

                    if(link['rel'] == 'messaging') {
                        console.log('messaging there')
                        if(embed.messaging) {
                            if(embed.messaging.state == "Disconnected") {
                                console.log("msgn Disconnected")
                                msg.addMsg = embed.messaging._links.addMessaging.href;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    console.log(msg)                                              
                };                  
            };               
        });
```

I have removed the result validation and simplified the for (var key in event) to handle both operations in one. Also, I have removed the arrays which I was pushing the values into as I was not using that. That may have been the time consuming factor which was preventing  me from getting the direction validated.